# Get function names from specific string

Tags: javascript

I have string with slash separated contains function names.

```
e.g.
my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()
```

Within above string I want only function name **i.e. getCustomer(), getControllerName() & getCsvFileName()**

I searched some regex like:

```
let res = myString.match(/(?<=(function\s))(\w+)/g);
```

but its returning result as null.

Update:
Now I want to get function names without parentheses `()` **i.e. getCustomer, getControllerName & getCsvFileName**

Please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = "my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()"

let tokens = [];

for (element of str.split("/"))
  if (element.endsWith("()"))
    tokens.push(element.split("=")[1] ?? element.split("=")[0])

console.log(tokens);
```

General idea: split the string along slashes, and for each of these tokens, if the token ends with `()` (as per Nick's suggestion), split the token along `=`. Append the second index of the token split along `=` if it exists, otherwise append the first.

A "smaller" version (using purely array methods) could be:

```js
const str = "my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()"

let tokens = str.split("/")
                .filter(element => element.endsWith("()"))
                .map(element => element.split("=")[1] ?? element.split("=")[0]);

console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: `.endsWith()` might make more sense than taking a substring.

Comment: @human-bean your code is working perfectly fine. 
Can I get function names without brackets ? 
e.g. getCustomer, getControllerName, getCsvFileName

Comment: Yes. Simply change the expressions `element.split("=")[1]` and `element.split("=")[0]` to `element.split("=")[1].slice(0, -2)` and `element.split("=")[0].slice(0, -2)`, respectively, to remove the trailing brackets for each element added to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string that has parentheses `()` first like `/.*?\([^)]*\)/g`.

This will give array of results, and after that you can iterate the array data and for each item, you can split the `=` and `/` before function name with the help of `item.split(/=|\//)`.

Then push the filtered function name into empty array `functionNames`.

**Working Example:**

```js
const string = `my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()`;

const functionNames = [];

string.match(/.*?\([^)]*\)/g).forEach(item => {
  const splitString = item.split(/=|\//);
  const functionName = splitString[splitString.length - 1];
  functionNames.push(functionName);
});

console.log(functionNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per, [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the match() method returns null if it does not find a match for the provided regex in the provided search string.

The regular expression which you have provided,`/(?<=(function\s))(\w+)/g` matches any word that has '**function** ' before it. (NOTE: a space after the word function)

Your search string `my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()` does not include 'function ' before any characters. That is why you got null as result of match() method.

```js
let yourString = 'my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()';

let myReferenceString = 'SAMPLETEXTfunction sayHi()/function sayHello()';


let res = yourString.match(/(?<=(function\s))(\w+)/g);
let res2 = myReferenceString.match(/(?<=(function\s))(\w+)/g);

console.log("Result of your string", res);
console.log("Result of my string", res2);
```

My solution here,

```js
let myreferenceString = 'my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()'

let res = myreferenceString.match(/((?<==)(\w+\(\)))|((?<=\/)(\w+\(\)))/g);

console.log("Result", res);
```

NOTE: I have used the 'Positive Look Behind regex operator', This is not supported in browsers like Safari and IE. Please do reasearch about this before considering this approach.